# I have a list of .c files along with the path stored in a list. Need to read each .c files(iterate) and list the .h files

Tags: python, regex, list

```
import os

for root,dirs,files in os.walk("mypath")

    for file in files:

                if file.endswith(".c"):

                                print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

For example:
I have a sample .c file. Inside it i have a code like this

#include "sample1.h"

#include "sample2.h"
...
...

Now i need to iterate through all the .c files i have and list the .h of each .c. i.e, sample1.h, samlpe2.h excluding #include ""

Comment: Please post your solution, only then someone can help you. no one is going to help you from start.

Comment: I'm new to python and i have added the code until getting the files. no i need to read the file and get the .h files alone in that .c file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dirpath which you call root. The dirnames are supplied so you can prune it if there are folders that you don't wish os.walk to recurs into.

```
import os
result = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, file in os.walk(PATH) for f in file if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.c']
```

with the use of glob

```
import os
from glob import glob
result = [y for x in os.walk(PATH) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.c'))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is just storing all the paths with file names in a list. But my question tells to take those files, open them, read and find out the #includes and list those .h inside #include. Thanks in advance.